# How to store all the dfs paths of a tree in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, tree, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

```
def traverse(node, path =[]):
    path.append(node.val)
    if len(node.children)==0:
       print(path)
       path.pop()
   else:
       for child in node.children:
           traverse(child)    
       path.pop()
```

The above code prints the depth-first search traversal of a tree like

[3, 2, 1, 4]

[3, 2, 5]

But it just prints these value, I want to store it in a list and want to return the list as

[ [ 3,2,1,4 ] , [ 3,2,5 ] ].

What modifications should I do to the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a simple modification will help you out!

```
def traverse(node, result=[], path =[]):
    path.append(node.val)
    if len(node.children)==0:
        print(path)
        result.append(path.copy())
        path.pop()
    else:
        for child in node.children:
            traverse(child)
        path.pop()
    return result
```

Copy the path into a list called "result" and return it.

Comment: @ShwetaSharma Welcome!